# Basic MVC routing (amibigous route issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 3 actions on my controller, none of which should have a route apart from their parameters.

```
[Route("")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
// List of things
    return View();
}

[Route("")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
// Specific 'thing'
    return View();
}

[Route("")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Detail(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
// 'Thing' has just been posted
    return View();
}
```

I get a 'call is ambiguous' error when trying to call the first, a 404 on the second (i.e. "/area/1001"). How must I configure my routes here?

I'd like to hit

- Index() with '/area/'
- Detail(int id) with '/area/123' and
- Detail(MyViewModel myViewModel) with a post to '/area/'

### EDIT

I know I can add `[Route("{id:int}")]` to the second action, but not sure about the third.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're decorating your actions with a blank route attribute?

Comment: @Luke - is it unnecessary?

Comment: you are getting you are getting ambiguous because you have two http get with the same route you need to add to detail action the id in the route, Regarding: "I know I can add [Route("{id:int}")] to the second action, but not sure about the third" You can and it will not be ambiguous because the http verb is different (HttpPost) but you don't need to because is a post in a put you will probably need to add the id and again it wont be ambiguous because is different http verb,

Comment: @LuisPalacios - you lost me a little bit. I don't need to what?

Comment: Sorry i edited the comment i mean "You can add the "[Route("{id:int}")]" to the third action" and you wont get ambiguous because is a different http verb (HttpPost)

Comment: Got ya! Thanks very much for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[RoutePrefix("Area")]
public AreaController : Controller {
    //GET Area
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        // List of things
        return View();
    }

    //GET Area/123
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Detail(int id) {
        // Specific 'thing'
        return View();
    }

    //POST Area
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Detail(MyViewModel myViewModel) {
        // 'Thing' has just been posted
        return View();
    }
}
```

make sure you have attribute routing configured

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    //...other code
}
```

Comment: The action link isn't working with this approach, frustrating. I have `@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Detail", "ControllerName", new { @id = 1001 }, null)` But it renders it like `Detail?id=1001`, which doesn't hit the action. Only `Detail/1001` hits the action (I prefer the slash option).

Comment: Update your question with how you are configuring your routes. the frame work will generate the urls using templates in the route table.

Comment: My guess would be that you'd have to specify a name for your route and use @Html.RouteLink() instead. `[Route("{id:int}", Name = "AreaDetail")]` and `@Html.RouteLink("AreaDetail", "my link" new { id = 1001 })`.  This is the problem with attribute routing, it's not as generic, readable and easily abused.

Comment: @Luke - you're right, I've just noticed RouteConfig has been amended - putting all of the responsibility on the attributes to define routing, and it's causing me problems. Thanks for your reply mate.

Comment: I personally prefer the normal route configuration instead of the attributes.

Comment: I've been able to use it without having to specify a name. If the attribute routing has been configured properly it generated the url using the first matching template which in this case would have been form the attribute routes and prefix.

Comment: Convention-based and attribute routing can work simultaneously in an MVC project.

Comment: Ok then, then we're missing something from this to make it pick up the route.  Is it the RoutePrefix?

Comment: @Luke that is why I asked to see how routes were configured. It is usually something simple like registering routes in wrong order. From what the OP is describing, it is taking the route from the convention-based config.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I take it when you gave your example in the previous comment, you have replaced `ControllerName` will the correct controller name, in this case `Area`?